# Error in Submit handler for custom node add form

Tags: 7, forms, theming

Trying to theme my own node add form with hook_theme() in my own module. In the *.tpl.php page for the node add form, submit button is not actually adding the content to database.

Issue: Why is "php print render($buttons);" not adding the right submit handler that actually adds a node (Content) entry.

In my stories.module file:

```
 /* Implements hook_theme().
 */
/*
function stories_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'stories_node_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'stories-node-form',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'stories'),
    ),
  );
}
*/

function template_preprocess_stories_node_form(&$variables){

    $variables['sidebar'] = array();   // Put taxonomy fields in sidebar.

    $variables['sidebar'][] = $variables['form']['field_tags'];
    hide($variables['form']['field_tags']);

    // Extract the form buttons, and put them in independent variable.
    $variables['buttons'] = $variables['form']['actions'];
    //hide($variables['form']['actions']);
 }
```

In stories-node-form.tpl.php:

```
    <div id="stories-add-wrapper">
<div class="nicname_and_category">
    <?php //print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
    <div class="input_auteur">
        <?php print render($form['field_nicname']); ?>
    </div>  

    <div class="input_cat">
        <?php print render($form['field_email']); ?>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="title_and_category">
    <div class="title">
        <?php print render($form['title']); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="category">
        <?php print render($form['field_category']);  ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php print render($form['field_share_your_story']);        ?>

<?php print render($buttons); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Found the solution.

Needed to add the following to the end of stories-node-form.tpl.php


<?php
print drupal_render_children($form); 
?>

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Needed to add `print drupal_render_children($form);` to the end of `stories-node-form.tpl.php`